# CPU architecture tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

#### x86 family

The x86 family is, unsurprisingly, the messiest.

- [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) is the most generic tag, and the most widely used.
- There are tags for x86 subfamilies: [8086](/questions/tagged/8086), [i386](/questions/tagged/i386), [ia32](/questions/tagged/ia32), [pentium](/questions/tagged/pentium). In practice, [x86](/questions/tagged/x86), [i386](/questions/tagged/i386), [ia32](/questions/tagged/ia32) and [pentium](/questions/tagged/pentium) seem to be used mostly interchangeably. [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) looks more specific to 8086. What should we do?

  - Merge [i386](/questions/tagged/i386), [ia32](/questions/tagged/ia32) and [pentium](/questions/tagged/pentium) into [x86](/questions/tagged/x86)?
  - Do a clean-up effort and reserve [i386](/questions/tagged/i386) for issues specific to i386 (or to i386 and i486?), reserve [ia-32](/questions/tagged/ia-32) for issues specific to i386 and above, and use [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) for generation-independent questions only? What about questions specific to more recent x86 generations (when they're not [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) or [sse2](/questions/tagged/sse2))?
  - A variant of the above, where [ia-32](/questions/tagged/ia-32) and [i386](/questions/tagged/i386) are synonyms?
  - Other proposals?

Then we have [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) (the usual vendor-neutral name), but also [x64](/questions/tagged/x64). [amd64](/questions/tagged/amd64) is already a synonym of [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64). Shall we merge [x64](/questions/tagged/x64) with [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) as well?

There's an [intel](/questions/tagged/intel) tag, which contains a lot of [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) or [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) questions. They should be retagged, right?

#### ARM

Strangely, I found nothing wrong around ARM families. (Note: ARM7 and ARMv7 are **not** the same thing.)

#### “Exotic” CPU families

The [alpha](/questions/tagged/alpha) tag is used for alpha channels in images. There's only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798242/recovering-data-from-a-vax-to-an-ntfs-system) question about the CPU architecture, and it's off-topic anyway.

[ppc](/questions/tagged/ppc) is used for both [powerpc](/questions/tagged/powerpc) and [pay-per-click](/questions/tagged/pay-per-click). This looks like a simple disambiguation job (and some of the [pay-per-click](/questions/tagged/pay-per-click) questions might be better off on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but I don't know if there are any still there that should be migrated).

[motorola](/questions/tagged/motorola) is a sponsored tag, which seems to be mostly about Motorola mobile phones and tablets. There are a few [68000](/questions/tagged/68000) questions in there.